# Spinner not showing drop-down in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working with `Fragments` in my current app. I tried using a Spinner in one of the fragments, to sort the `listview` below it in a specific format. The `Adapter` is set correctly, but I'm unable to open the dropdown on touch to select the choices. How I know the adapter is set correctly, is that in the `AVD`, I'm able to navigate to it using the keyboard and open it.

**Code:**

```
public class Upcoming_Reminders extends Fragment {


private View view;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private ListView listView;
private String TAG = "Loggin";
RemindersAdapter remindersAdapter;
private Spinner mSortSpinner;
private String[] test;

public Upcoming_Reminders() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mSortSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sort_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mSortAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
    mSortAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSortSpinner.setAdapter(mSortAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming__reminders, container, false);
    test = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sort_by);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contracts_list);

    return view;
}
```

I tried putting it in the `OnCreateView` method as well, below the view assignment. It still isn't clickable.

**The XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.onerooftechnologiesamc.Upcoming_Reminders">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/te"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:text="@string/sort_by" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sort_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout></FrameLayout>
```

What could be the cause? I tried Googling a lot, haven't found someone with the exact same problem as me.

Thank you

Edit 1: The Resources file

```
<resources>
<array name="sort_by">
    <item>Option 1</item>
    <item>Option 2</item>
    <item>Option 3</item>
    <item>Option 4</item>
</array></resources>
```

Comment: try this **`ArrayAdapter<String> mSortSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);`**

Comment: Didn't work!

The problem is mostly with the Spinner and not the adapter in itself. The adapter is loading perfectly.

If I remember correctly, Spinners without adapters will also be clickable but show a blank dropdown instead.

Comment: Could you please show your array file

Comment: Edited into OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been with FrameLayout. I switched to a RelativeLayout and it started working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SpinnerFragment extends Fragment {

private Spinner spinner;
private String[] test = {"1","2","3","4","5"};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spinner,container,false);
    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mSortAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
    mSortAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(mSortAdapter);
    return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
    {

     private Activity context;
      String[] data = null;

   public SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, int resource, 
          String[] data2)
    {
      super(context, resource, data2);
      this.context = context;
      this.data = data2;
    }
    ...

   @Override
   public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, 
     ViewGroup parent)
     {   
       View row = convertView;
       if(row == null)
 {
     //inflate your customlayout for the textview
     LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
     row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, parent, false);
 }
 //put the data in it
 String item = data[position];
 if(item != null)
 {   
    TextView text1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
    text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    text1.setText(item);
 }

 return row;
 }
 ...
}
```

and then set the adapter for the spinner:

```
  Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
  final String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(
             R.array.data);
  final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(
        MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        data);
  mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Populates the spinner alright, can still see the choices using the keyboard, but isn't clickable like all spinners

Comment: I have tried this and this is working perfectly fine in my device. Check the below code

Comment: Have you implemented it in an activity or in a fragment? This will work in an activity for sure, it isn't working in a fragment

Comment: Yes this code is for activity but the below code is working fine in fragment.